# Bold and Italics are not working in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: html, css

Bold `<b></b>` and Italics `<i></i>` tags render correctly on the iPhone and Internet Explorer, but there is no formatting in Firefox or Chrome.

Here are the .css files.  I also tried to add in `i { font-style:italic; }` separately in Reset and Style.

```
Color.css:

body {
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url(../img/background-red.png);
}

Reset.css:

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
input, textarea, button
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul, dl {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


Style.css:

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;  

    font: normal 18px/1.4 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.panel {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    background: #fff;

    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
}


.content {
    max-width: 45%;
    margin: 100px;

    float: left;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;    
}

h1 {
    font-size: 72px;
    line-height: 56px;
    font-weight: 300;    
}

h2 {
    margin: 15px 0 50px;    

    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;    
    font-weight: 300;    
}
```

**Here is the HTML, I tried using `<strong>asdf</strong>` to see if it would make text bold but it does not.**

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>adssda</h1>
    <h2>dasdasdsa</h2>

<p><i><strong>sadsad</strong>asdsad</i></p><br>
sadasddsa<br><br>
<strong>asdasd</strong><br><br>
    <p><strong>asdasd</strong></p><br>
</div>
```

Why does the bold text look the same as normal text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `font: inherit` in your main reset block(the first one under the reset header) is causing all of your fonts on the page to be reset.  Indeed, [not even fixing the invalid html to be valid fixes this](http://jsfiddle.net/GSySV/1/), your css in mind.

Commenting out this property [fixes your text](http://jsfiddle.net/GSySV/).

Comment: There is a closing bracket, accidentally missed that when posting. I removed the font: inherit part but unfortunately it is still the same even after fixing the strong HTML issue.

Comment: @userrandomnums If your website is online..  could you link to it?  It would make it easier to debug, given that it should work as shown in the last demo.

Comment: Hey, I think it's actually working. My friend said she sees the formatting so I guess it must be my cache. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @userrandomnums Welcome; glad I was able to assist.

Answer (score 6):

Firefox has trouble with certain tags like `<b>`, `<strong>` and `<i>` tags for some reason.  It is a bug in the firefox browser itself.  Try a different version of firefox and things will be different.

Here is the workaround that works for everybody, Add this to your CSS file:

```
strong, b {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

It's a CSS override.  Now firefox renders bold text **like this** instead of like this.

Answer (score 0):

Now replace into this code

```
<p><strong><i>sadsad</strong>asdsad</i></p><br>
sadasddsa<br><br>
<strong>asdasd</strong><br><br>
    <p><strong>asdasd</strong></p><br>
```

**into this**

```
<p><strong><i>sadsad</i></strong><i>asdsad</i></p><br>
sadasddsa<br><br>
<strong>asdasd</strong><br><br>
    <p><strong>asdasd</strong></p><br>
```

**[LIve Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/qXuy0Een)**

Answer (score 0):

It's because your HTML is malformed.

You're closing the `</strong>` before the `</i>`

Should be

```
<div class="content">
     <h1>adssda</h1>
     <h2>dasdasdsa</h2>
    <p><i><strong>sadsad</strong>asdsad</i></p>
    <br>
    sadasddsa
    <br>
    <br>
    <strong>asdasd</strong>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p><strong>asdasd</strong></p>
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its TAG closing mistake, in HTML

```
<p><strong><i>sadsad</strong>asdsad</i></p><br>
```

this should be like this

```
<p><i><strong>sadsad</strong>asdsad</i></p><br />
```

Open tag must closed with in the same tag it is to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML elements are in tree structure.
Your elements are not closed as they were open.
for example-

```
<div>
<p>
<i>
<strong> sadsad
</strong>
</i>
</p>
</div>
```